# Distinct users per time from duration and datetime using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this dataset

```
created_at                  user_id    duration (second)
2019-02-21 11:32:57.000     A          50
2019-02-21 11:32:57.000     B          100
2019-02-21 11:35:00.000     B          70
```

My goal is to know distinct user_id per minute that still open our app. for example

```
date           time       count
2019-02-21     11:32      2
2019-02-21     11:33      2
2019-02-21     11:34      1
2019-02-21     11:35      1
2019-02-21     11:36      1
```

Comment: Can you explain what logic you have applied to obtain the count?

Comment: add the duration to created_at, for example if you click at 12:00 and your duration is 150 second, it means that you active from 12:00 to 12:02 so this user should be counted on 12:00, 12:01 and 12:02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Self-contained example followed by the steps***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'created_at': ['2019-02-21 11:32:57.000', 
                                  '2019-02-21 11:32:57.000', 
                                  '2019-02-21 11:35:00.000'], 
                   'user_id': ['A', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'duration':[50, 100, 70]})


df['session_index'] = df.index
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df['dtm_start'] = df['created_at'].dt.floor(freq='min')
df['dtm_end'] = (df['created_at'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='seconds')).dt.floor(freq='min')



df_melt = pd.melt(df, 
                  id_vars=['user_id', 'session_index'], 
                  value_vars=['dtm_start', 'dtm_end'], 
                  value_name='active_min').sort_values(by=['session_index', 
                                                           'user_id',
                                                           'active_min'])

df_melt['col_1'] = 1
df_melt = df_melt.set_index('active_min')

all_active_mins = df_melt.groupby(['user_id', 'session_index'])['col_1'].resample('60S').sum().reset_index()

active_users_by_min = all_active_mins.active_min.value_counts()

active_users_by_min
```

[image]

---

***Step-wise outputs***

```
df['session_index'] = df.index
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df['dtm_start'] = df['created_at'].dt.floor(freq='min')
df['dtm_end'] = (df['created_at'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='seconds')).dt.floor(freq='min')
df
```

[image]

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df, 
                  id_vars=['user_id', 'session_index'], 
                  value_vars=['dtm_start', 'dtm_end'], 
                  value_name='active_min').sort_values(by=['session_index', 
                                                           'user_id',
                                                           'active_min'])

df_melt['col_1'] = 1
df_melt = df_melt.set_index('active_min')
df_melt
```

[image]

```
all_active_mins = df_melt.groupby(['user_id', 'session_index'])['col_1'].resample('60S').sum().reset_index()
all_active_mins
```

[image]

```
all_active_mins.active_min.value_counts()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
# STEP 1:
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df['end_at'] = df['created_at'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['duration (second)'], unit='s')

# STEP 2:
df1 = df.melt(id_vars='user_id', value_vars=['created_at', 'end_at'], value_name='ts')

# STEP 3:
df1 = (
    df1[['user_id', 'ts']].groupby('user_id', group_keys=False)
    .apply(lambda s: s.drop_duplicates().set_index('ts').resample('1min').ffill().bfill())
)

# STEP 4
df1 = df1.groupby(level=0).nunique().set_axis(['count'], 1)

# STEP 5:
df1 = df1.assign(date=df1.index.date, time=df1.index.time).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Steps:

```
# STEP 1: df
           created_at user_id  duration (second)              end_at
0 2019-02-21 11:32:57       A                 50 2019-02-21 11:33:47
1 2019-02-21 11:32:57       A                 50 2019-02-21 11:33:47
2 2019-02-21 11:32:57       B                100 2019-02-21 11:34:37
3 2019-02-21 11:35:00       B                 70 2019-02-21 11:36:10

# STEP 2: df1
  user_id    variable                  ts
0       A  created_at 2019-02-21 11:32:57
1       A  created_at 2019-02-21 11:32:57
2       B  created_at 2019-02-21 11:32:57
3       B  created_at 2019-02-21 11:35:00
4       A      end_at 2019-02-21 11:33:47
5       A      end_at 2019-02-21 11:33:47
6       B      end_at 2019-02-21 11:34:37
7       B      end_at 2019-02-21 11:36:10

# STEP 3: df1
                    user_id
ts                         
2019-02-21 11:32:00       A
2019-02-21 11:33:00       A
2019-02-21 11:32:00       B
2019-02-21 11:33:00       B
2019-02-21 11:34:00       B
2019-02-21 11:35:00       B
2019-02-21 11:36:00       B

# STEP 4: df1
                     count
ts                        
2019-02-21 11:32:00      2
2019-02-21 11:33:00      2
2019-02-21 11:34:00      1
2019-02-21 11:35:00      1
2019-02-21 11:36:00      1

# STEP 5 (RESULT): df1
   count        date      time
0      2  2019-02-21  11:32:00
1      2  2019-02-21  11:33:00
2      1  2019-02-21  11:34:00
3      1  2019-02-21  11:35:00
4      1  2019-02-21  11:36:00
```

Comment: Error on step 2. ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Comment: I guess you have same`user_id` with a same `created_at` timestamp multiple times, edited the code, let me know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: on step 2 KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'

Comment: @OctavianWR Can you show the output  of `df` after the step 1?

Comment: created_at user_id duration end_at